# Having trouble creating credentials in google console for sign in integration

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have developed a simple android app using firebase and has sign in with google facility. Everything was working fine up until I decided to create the new signed APK. While working with the debug key I was able to create the google credentials properly, it created both the android and web client IDs as shown in the screenshot 
[Credentials screenshot with debug key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKDHH.jpg)

where according to the google documentation we need to pass the web client ID while creating the `GoogleSignInOptions` object. Now when I decided to create the actual signed APK. It generated new SHA1 fingerprint. And when I am trying to create the credentials with this new SHA1 fingerprint, it is only creating android client ID but not the web client ID as shown in this screenshot
[Credentials screenshot with release fingerprint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYTlt.jpg)

My question, how do I create the new credentials with the new key, as sign in is failing with this android client ID?

**Solution:**

We can solve this either by creating new google console project or as I did simply by updating the existing project's signature from the console credentials screen as highlighted [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqWMr.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know you cannot have 2 applications with associated with the same package name on the google developer api console.

go to: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating and scroll down to the "Configure a Project" button.

Create your new application via the wizard. As an alternate you can do this via https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials

At this point you will need your app package name and the debug/prod signing key SHA-1. Find the key that you will use to sign your app and via your terminal use:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias key_alias -keypass key_pass -keystore location/file.jks -storepass store_password -file myKey.crt -rfc
```

followed by:

```
keytool -printcert myKey.crt
```

This will print all your hashes to the terminal including SHA-1 which you can then copy to the wizard we mentioned above.

You are looking for something like: `0C:F5:85:40:F3:1B:42:A2:EB:DC:FD:CA:12:6F:G5:3D:0B:3C:32:21`

Make sure you delete the myKey.crt once you no longer use/need it...

Note: *In order to get the debug build hashes you don't need to play around with the keytool. Just go and open the gradle tab in your android studio -> tasks -> android -> signingReport and double click it and open the gradle console output and search for your SHA-1*

After the wizard has created your new credentials which should have both OAuth client and Web Client you download the credentials.json and put it in your app folder

```
AppName/app/credentials.json
```

If you have debug credentials they will not work on release signed builds and vice versa. I had this problem very recently and spent lots of time on it, so if this can help someone I will be more than glad :)

Comment: Yeah, it was something similar to you mentioned, I was able to solve the issue by just updating the package name and SHA1 fingerprint on the existing project's android client highlighted in the new screenshot attached. Thanks!